# PostgreSQL negate a numeric value in resultset

Tags: java, postgresql, sql, select-query

I have a query to return a `resultset` of `decimal(30,12)` type data.

```
SELECT sales from invoice_index;
```

This query is giving me output like this:

```
sales
------
100
-200
300
```

But I need an output as follow:

```
sales
----
-100
200
-300
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To negate a value, just multiply it with `-1`.

```
SELECT sales * (-1) from invoice_index;
```